# What fantasy book had a man transported to another world who became able to turn into a dragon?

Tags: story-identification

I read a book, over ten years ago now, and if I recall it seemed like it was maybe the second or third book in the series. It was about a man who had either been pulled into a book, or the past. (I'm not 100% sure as to which it was) and once there he was made lord of the Castle and could transform into a dragon.

It seems that he might also have been able to use other forms of magic, and that his wife or girlfriend (again, I am fuzzy on the details) was also with him. I really enjoyed the book and now I would like to see if there was more to the series, and I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me what it was I read.

Thanks

Comment: The title of your question hints that there is something about a librarian, but there is no mention of a librarian or a library in your actual question. Did the castle have a library? Was the man a librarian in the real world, before he got pulled into a book or the past?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15045/man-can-do-magic-by-writing-spells-on-the-inside-of-his-mind/15127#15127

Answer (score 8):

It could possibly be The Dragon and the George by Gordon R. Dickson.

Transformed to a dragon - check

Has wife or girlfriend - check (actually fiancee)

[Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dragon_and_the_George)

Comment: Was there anything to do with a Librarian?

Comment: He was an academic, so it could be the OP misremembering.

Comment: Also made into an animated film with John Ritter in 1982. Flight of Dragons. Specifically talks about science vs. Magic.

Comment: @beichst good catch - I came here specifically to mention "Flight of Dragons" but I guess you beat me to it. Also, I didn't know it was based on a book. Might have to read it now.