# Book about man who travels back in time to Middle Ages and can turn into a dragon

Tags: story-identification, books

I am trying to find a book I read in the 90's. It is about a man who traveled back in time to the Middle Ages. He can turn into a dragon and there is a big war against serpents. If I remember correctly there is a part where he magically travels under water and talks to a huge octopus.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15045/man-can-do-magic-by-writing-spells-on-the-inside-of-his-mind/15127#15127

Answer (score 9):

[The Dragon And The George](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/114936.The_Dragon_and_the_George) by [Gordon R.Dickson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon_R._Dickson). From [Amazon's description](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Dragon-George-Cycle-Book-ebook/dp/B005LB9HWA):

> "One minute he was a college teacher, the next he was a dragon! Jim
>   Eckert leads a peaceful, happy campus life. He's a college basketball
>   player and an expert in mediaeval history.
>
> But his life has been disrupted by the disappearance of his girlfriend
>   Angie. While taking part in a laboratory experiment on astral
>   projection she just vanished.
>
> In an attempt to find out what's happened he submits himself to the
>   equipment. A very unwise move Next thing he knows he's in the Middle
>   Ages. Worse, he's no longer human. He's in the body of a dragon. Worse
>   still, Angie has been nabbed by another dragon and taken to the
>   Loathly Tower. Obviously, Jim has no option but to give chase . . .

Comment: The animated film "Flight of Dragons" was based on this, although there are numerous differences (as usual).

Comment: This series includes several books.  He does go underwater at one point, into the realm where King Arthur's knights await the time of their return, slays wurms, and generally does all sorts of do-goodery.  The magic system is interesting, as all magic is fueled by karma, and is tracked by an Accounting Department to make certain people don't spend more karma than they make.

Comment: @Omegacron The movie is a mish-mash of the novel and the "non-fiction" book [The Flight of Dragons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flight_of_Dragons_(book)) which tries to scientifically explain dragons.